# Prestashop - get products with condition

Tags: php, prestashop

How do I get products with condition, for example all products with 0 quantity?
I use getProducts function, but there are no option for condition.

```
/**
* Get all available products
*
* @param integer $id_lang Language id
* @param integer $start Start number
* @param integer $limit Number of products to return
* @param string $order_by Field for ordering
* @param string $order_way Way for ordering (ASC or DESC)
* @return array Products details
*/
public static function getProducts($id_lang, $start, $limit, $order_by, $order_way, $id_category = false,
    $only_active = false, Context $context = null) {...}
```

I thought about to add condition after the get, but it is gobbling up more resources:

```
$products = $category->getProducts($this->context->language->id, 1, 100);
$condition_products;
foreach ($products as $key => $product)
{
   if (condition)
   {
        $condition_products .= $product
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to check qty in loop, possible to [override](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors) `getProducts` method and add any condition that you need.